# CSS column-fill auto ignores printed page breaks

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout

The column-fill:auto property works by first populating one full column before going to the next.

```
.two-column {
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

Chrome does this only correctly on screen, but not when printing and having to deal with page breaks:

```
A C
B D
---- page break
E G
F H
---- page break
I J  <-- two columns
```

However, the remaining part of the list that breaks into the last page, the layout reverts back to a "balanced"-style. At least, Chrome does, FireFox, displays it correctly:

```
A C
B D
---- page break
E G
F H
---- page break
I
J
```

Is this a (known) Chrome bug? Is there any workaround for it?

Example: https://codepen.io/Stu42/pen/PoqYYWo

**Update**: As pointed out by Juan Marco, this is likely a Chrome bug. As discussed here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4036. Any clear reference to a official bug or status, or better, a workaround would count as an answer, I think.

Comment: Have a [mcve] you can add to the question in order to demonstrate this?

Comment: +2,5yrs: Looks like people are working on implementing this in something called "css-multicol-1" https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/projects/4#card-22807684

Comment: Multicolumn layout is a [module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/) that has been CR since last year, and that all major browsers have largely supported for many years already.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I just ran into this issue. I was able to fix it by creating a child div within the containing element that sets up the grid, and then setting `break-inside` to `avoid`.

E.g., from your example, something like this:

```html
 <div class="two-column">
    <div style="break-inside: avoid;">
      <p>A</p>
      <p>B</p>
      <p>C</p>
      <p>D</p>
      <p>E</p>
      <p>F</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This causes the last page to *not* break the two paragraphs apart so you end up with this structure:

```
A C
B D
---- page break
E
F
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Works for me, But this adding extra blank page while generating pdf

Comment: @SurajParise I also use this for generating a PDF and didn't have that problem. Most likely there is extra margin or padding at the end of your document that is causing another page break. (I ran into a similar issue and realized I had a margin-bottom declaration that was causing the extra page.)

Answer (score 0):

For [`column-fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill) MDN says:

> Note that there are some interoperability issues and bugs with column-fill across browsers, due to unresolved issues in the specification.

Whenever you plan to use a feature that's experimental or not well supported check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) for info. Then use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to get the necessary vendor prefixes (if any).

For example, for the style rule:

```
.two-column {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1cm;
    column-fill: auto;
    background-color: #faa;
}
```

Autoprefixer generated this:

```
.two-column {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1cm;
       -moz-column-gap: 1cm;
            column-gap: 1cm;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
       -moz-column-fill: auto;
            column-fill: auto;
    background-color: #faa;
}
```

Comment: that is nice, wasn't aware of any of that... however, very unfortunately, this doesn't "fix" Chrome. Updated my example with the generated auto prefixes.

Comment: Glad that was informative. When I researched `column-fill`, I found an [open issue regarding the way it behaves in paginated and continuous contexts](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4036). You might need to find an alternative until it's resolved.

Comment: Ok, so looks to be a Chrome bug.. too bad.